# Google Geocharts- Getting Marker of same size on calling of json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-visualization

Please help me to solve this issue. I am getting marker of same size whereas I want marker size should vary depending on its value. 
My code

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCXy0BKw58SlhIj-KHgtu3IGSk8JV8X2JI" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $.getJSON("jsonp.json", function foo(result) {
  google.charts.load('upcoming', {'packages': ['geochart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);
  var jsonRequestUrl = 'jsonp.json';
  var elements = result["Jobs Data - City Occurances"];
  elements = JSON.stringify(elements);                       // <====
  elements = JSON.parse(elements);

  function drawMarkersMap() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('string', 'City');
     data.addColumn('string', 'Occurances');
     data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
     data.addRows(elements.length);
     $.each(elements, function (index, value) {
      data.setCell(index,0,elements[index].City);
      data.setCell(index,1,elements[index].Occurances);
      data.setCell(index,2,elements[index].City);
     });

   var options = {
     region: 'US',
     displayMode: 'markers',
     colorAxis:{
       minValue: 0,
       maxValue:600,
      colors:['blue','green','red']
      },
     resolution: 'provinces'
   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
 };

 });
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**jsonp.json file**

```
{
 "Jobs Data - City Occurances": [
  {
    "City": "new york",
    "Occurances": "555"
  },
  {
    "City": "inglewood",
    "Occurances": "1"
  },
  {
    "City": "houston",
    "Occurances": "296"
  },
  {
    "City": "montgomery center",
    "Occurances": "275"
  },
  {
    "City": "dallas",
    "Occurances": "259"
  },
  {
    "City": "san diego",
    "Occurances": "197"
  },
  {
    "City": "detroit",
    "Occurances": "187"
  },

  {
    "City": "philadelphia",
    "Occurances": "118"
  },
  {
    "City": "richfield",
    "Occurances": "115"
  }

]
}
```

I want result someting like this [geocharts](http://codepen.io/priya_singh/pen/amRmVJ).
But after adding data from json I am getting marker of same size.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `'Occurances'` column should be numeric

`data.addColumn('number', 'Occurances');`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var result = {"Jobs Data - City Occurances": [
      {
        "City": "new york",
        "Occurances": "555"
      },
      {
        "City": "inglewood",
        "Occurances": "1"
      },
      {
        "City": "houston",
        "Occurances": "296"
      },
      {
        "City": "montgomery center",
        "Occurances": "275"
      },
      {
        "City": "dallas",
        "Occurances": "259"
      },
      {
        "City": "san diego",
        "Occurances": "197"
      },
      {
        "City": "detroit",
        "Occurances": "187"
      },
      {
        "City": "philadelphia",
        "Occurances": "118"
      },
      {
        "City": "richfield",
        "Occurances": "115"
      }
    ]};

    var elements = result["Jobs Data - City Occurances"];
    elements = JSON.stringify(elements);
    elements = JSON.parse(elements);

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'City');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Occurances');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
    data.addRows(elements.length);
    $.each(elements, function (index, value) {
      data.setCell(index,0,elements[index].City);
      data.setCell(index,1,parseFloat(elements[index].Occurances));
      data.setCell(index,2,elements[index].City);
    });

    var options = {
      region: 'US',
      displayMode: 'markers',
      colorAxis:{
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue:600,
        colors:['blue','green','red']
      },
      resolution: 'provinces'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['geochart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. Its working fine. I am having lots of data in the form of Json. Is there any way to increase speed for loading data.

Comment: Still it is too slow.

Comment: yes. I used google.visualization.DataTable(elements);

Comment: not sure what else, where is most of the time, during `$.getJSON` or after? also, recommend loading google first, then `$.getJSON`